# Is there a CSS property which, when you set an object's position to relative and move it and resize it, it doesn't change its containers size?

Tags: css

So, I have a footer bar, it's got buttons in it. I'm trying to adjust the position of one of the buttons in order to give it more space. I want to move it up 10px and increase its height but when i do that it acts as if its in its original position and moves all the other buttons up, how do i make it so that it doesn't do that?

```
/*There's little space between it and the windows navigation bar*/
#syncButton {
    width: 100px;
    height: 18px;
}
```

[image: There's little space between it and the windows navigation bar]

```
/*There's lots of space between it and the windows navigation bar*/
#syncButton {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 38px;
}
```

[image: There's lots of space between it and the windows navigation bar]

Comment: Use a `translate` transformation, instead of relative positioning. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use `display: inline-flex` and set the `align-items` property to `center` and the `justify-content` property to `center`.

```css
body {
    margin: 2rem;
}

#syncButton {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 38px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<button id="syncButton">Sync Button</button>
```